# Joomla php function which prints the pagename

Tags: php, development, templates

Is there a php function to insert in the template which prints the name of the menu item of the displayed page?

Comment: Welcome to JSE,  please take our [tour].  Can you please edit your question to include any research/attempts that you've already done? By showing us which documentation pages you have already read, volunteers will know that they do not need to be recommended to you.

Comment: have you tried `echo Factory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive()->title;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the name of the menu item is called "Page Heading" in the Joomla! backend, first you need to have is this option enabled .

- Go to the **Global Configuration** > **Menus** > and change **"Show Page Heading"** to **"Yes"**
- You also have this option into your menu items, in the tab called **"Page Display"**, by default is enabled.

So, the code is generated by **com_content**, and here is the code:

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('show_page_heading')) : ?>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1> <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?> </h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you need to add this code, maybe the best optión is create an [override](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager) for one of the **com_content options**, once this is done you can find a folder called html inside your template.

Hope this helps.